# Optimizing SQLite Inner Join Query - Android

Tags: android, database, sqlite, join, gtfs

I am working with GTFS and trying to figure out a way to speed up my inner join. The tables "Trips" and "StopTimes" have a common column "TripID" and the tables "StopTimes" and "Stops" have a common column "StopID". The inner join retrieves all Stops that correspond to a certain Trip, however it takes about 20 seconds. Also the "StopTimes" table consists of 9 million rows while the others consists of a couple thousand. The following code is my query.

```
String joinQuery = "SELECT s.stop_id, s.stop_code, s.stop_name "
+ "FROM Trips as t INNER JOIN StopTimes as st ON     st.trip_id = t.trip_id "
+ "INNER JOIN Stops as s ON s.stop_id = st.stop_id "
+ "WHERE t.trip_id = " + TripID + " AND t.shape_id = " + ShapeID
+ " ORDER BY st.stop_sequence";
```

This is the code executed upon database creation.

```
String CREATE_TRIPS_TABLE = "CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE " + TABLE_TRIPS + " USING FTS3("
            + KEY_T_ROUTE_ID + " INTEGER,"
            + KEY_T_NAME + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_TRIP_ID + " INTEGER,"
            + KEY_DIRECTION_ID + " INTEGER,"
            + KEY_SHAPE_ID + " INTEGER);";

    String CREATE_STOPS_TABLE = "CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE " + TABLE_STOPS + " USING FTS3("
            + KEY_STOP_ID + " INTEGER,"
            + KEY_STOP_CODE + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_STOP_NAME + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_STOP_LAT + " DOUBLE,"
            + KEY_STOP_LON + " DOUBLE,"
            + KEY_STOP_WHEELCHAIR + " INTEGER);";

    String CREATE_STOPTIMES_TABLE = "CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE " + TABLE_STOP_TIMES + " USING FTS3("
            + KEY_S_TRIP_ID + " INTEGER,"
            + KEY_S_STOP_ID + " INTEGER,"
            + KEY_ARRIVAL_TIME + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_STOP_SEQUENCE + " INTEGER,"
            + KEY_SHAPE_DIST_TRAVELLED + " DOUBLE);";
```

I followed a few suggestion I found on here and am still not able to speed up my query, any feedback is appreciated.

**UPDATE**
I changed how my tables were created and added indexes for  two of the indexes involved in the INNER JOIN query and the JOINS are now instant.

```
String CREATE_TRIPS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_TRIPS + "("
            + KEY_T_ID + " integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
            + KEY_T_ROUTE_ID + " INTEGER,"
            + KEY_T_NAME + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_TRIP_ID + " INTEGER,"
            + KEY_DIRECTION_ID + " INTEGER,"
            + KEY_SHAPE_ID + " INTEGER);";

    String CREATE_STOPS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_STOPS + "("
            + KEY_S_ID + " integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
            + KEY_STOP_ID + " INTEGER,"
            + KEY_STOP_CODE + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_STOP_NAME + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_STOP_LAT + " DOUBLE,"
            + KEY_STOP_LON + " DOUBLE,"
            + KEY_STOP_WHEELCHAIR + " INTEGER);";

    String CREATE_STOPTIMES_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_STOP_TIMES + "("
            + KEY_ST_ID + " integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
            + KEY_S_TRIP_ID + " INTEGER,"
            + KEY_S_STOP_ID + " INTEGER,"
            + KEY_ARRIVAL_TIME + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_STOP_SEQUENCE + " INTEGER,"
            + KEY_SHAPE_DIST_TRAVELLED + " DOUBLE);";

    db.execSQL(CREATE_ROUTES_TABLE);
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TRIPS_TABLE);
    db.execSQL(CREATE_STOPS_TABLE);
    db.execSQL(CREATE_STOPTIMES_TABLE);
    db.execSQL("CREATE INDEX T_id ON Trips(trip_id)");
    db.execSQL("CREATE INDEX S_t_id ON StopTimes(trip_id)");
```

Comment: Why are you using [the FTS3 extension](https://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html) as opposed to building a normal relational database? Are you planning on doing full-text searches against the GTFS data?

Comment: @SimonSouth Yes, it's supposed to make searching through the data faster

Comment: I'm sure it makes _full-text_ searches faster, but I think it's working against you for the kind of query you show here (and the kind of queries normally run against GTFS data). I think you should first try defining the database in a conventional manner, with indices on the appropriate columns, and see how well your query performs before trying to get fancy with extensions.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I really appreciate it! I'll test it out and post my results

Comment: To emphasize my point: [SQLite does not allow indices on virtual tables](https://sqlite.org/lang_createvtab.html), which is probably the explanation for why your query takes so long to complete.

Comment: @SimonSouth Thanks for all the information, I am trying to mark your answer as the right one (green check mark and all) but I'm not sure how

Comment: That's because I haven't posted a true answer yet. I'll duplicate my comment as an answer, and then you can mark it as accepted (thanks!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you're using [SQLite's FTS3 extension](https://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html), which is designed to improve the performance of full-text searches. I suspect that's actually working against you for the kind of query you're issuing (and for the kinds of queries normally run against GTFS data).

I recommend you start by creating a conventional relational database, with indices on the appropriate columns, and testing the performance of your query against that. SQLite is certainly capable of good performance when used in this type of application so I think you'll be pleasantly surprised. Once you've demonstrated success with conventional techniques you can look into other ways to make the query run faster, if necessary.

Finally, note [SQLite does not allow indices on virtual tables](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createvtab.html), which I suspect is the specific reason your query is taking so long to complete right now.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the information, creating a conventional database really sped up the process. The trips with the most stops now take less than 10 seconds

Comment: Great! If you haven't defined indices on the tables yet, creating those should make a tremendous difference as well.

Comment: I'm confused, define indices? I thought I had already done that in the query

Comment: No; indices are created on the tables themselves, using the [`CREATE INDEX`](http://sqlite.org/lang_createindex.html) statement. Explaining how and why to use indices is a little too involved for a Stack Overflow answer, so you might want to refer to a book or tutorial on relational databases. As a rule of thumb, though, you generally want to create an index on each column used in either a `JOIN` or a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I'll definitely look into it. I appreciate all the information you've provided!

Comment: You're welcome. Best of luck with your application, and welcome to Stack Overflow!